# How to turn off contact shadows in "USDZ" file for AR Quick Look?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, ios12, usdz

We are working with `USDZ` files and are having trouble with contact shadows especially with transparent objects.

Questions:

1) Is there a way to turn off contact shadows?

The AR Quick Look presentation in WWDC says there is a way to turn off contact shadows, but I'm unable to find any documentation on how.

2) Should contact shadows in the case of transparent objects be handles differently?

Here's a capture of a wineglass object:

[image]

> Here you can download [USDZ model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R0bhuWhAVWt4lruUIDiJT38moJdkDqh2/view).

[image]

**Update 20/Nov/2018**: I have a bug report with Apple for this feature: https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46180332

**Update 22/Mar/2019**: Answered as well. Looks like this is now fixed in iOS 12.1.4.

Comment: I would try running the USDZ building command with `-h` to see if there are any clues in there. If there aren't any then you can use a support ticket to get a quick reply from Apple. You get two for free every year with your Developer Account.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an option here:

Comment: xcrun usdz_converter -h
-g groupName [groupNames ...] 
-m materialName [materialNames ...]  material(s).
-a usda file
-l Leave intermediate
-v verbose
-f filePath
-texCoordSet
-opacity
-specularColor        r g b
-useSpecularWorkflow  i
-color_map filePath
-normal_map filePath
-emissive_map filePath
-metallic_map filePath
-roughness_map filePath
-ao_map filePath
-color_default r g b a
-normal_default r g b a
-emissive_default r g b a
-metallic_default r g b a
-roughness_default r g b a
-ao_default  r g b a

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been fixed in iOS 12.1.4.

[image: AR Quicklook on iOS 12.1.4]